# How to prevent a div from increasing the value of an upvote after one click using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this div that perform an onclick event by increasing the value of an upvote when a user click on the div. It increment which is fine, but I only want it to increment only once even when the user clicks on the div multiple times.

Here is my code

```
btnUpvote(data) {
  let feeds = [...this.state.feeds]
  let feed = feeds.find(x => x.id === data.id)
  // feed.upvote +1
  let get = feed.upvote + 1
  console.log(get)
  if (feed.upvote !== get) {

  }

  this.setState({
    feeds
  })
}
```

The value of the feed.upvote is stored in an array of object, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can set the higher limit to 1 and lower limit to 0 by checking it after every onClick ,or another way would be to disable the button altogether after the first upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this condition :

```
 let get = 0
   if(!feed.upvote){
    get=  feed.upvote + 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store the id which has already been upvoted.
Check it and handle your clicks accordingly.

```
let allowOneClicks = [];

function allowOnce(id, callback) {
  if (allowOneClicks.includes(id)) return;

  allowOneClicks.push(id);
  callback();
}
```

In your case, it can be like this.

```
// outside your component;

const upvotedIds = [];

btnUpvote(data) {
  let feeds = [...this.state.feeds]
  let feed = feeds.find(x => x.id === data.id)
   
   if (upvotedIds.includes(id)) return;
    upvotedIds.push(id);

  // upvote here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
onHandleClick = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    feed: {
     ...this.state.feed,
     [id]: (this.state.feed[id] || 0) + 1
    }
  })
 }
```